# Clear timeout outside the launching scope?

Tags: javascript, timer

I can't find a way to stop the interval timer outside of the calling function. What am I missing in the following code? Do I need to specifically declare a global variable called `timer`?

```js
var timer;  // global timer?

function updateStats(i) {
     i++; // increment
     alert("Im running! increment is " + i);

     checkCondition(i);

     timer = setInterval(function() {
         updateStats(i);
     }, 5000);
}

function checkCondition(i) {
     if(i == 2) {
        alert("condition met, resetting timer!");
        clearInterval(timer);
     }
}

var i = 0;
updateStats(i);
```

Comment: @adeneo That's only one problem. Even if he used `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` there would still be a problem. The problem is that the OP is clearing `timer` when `i == 2` and then immediately setting the `timer` again.

Answer (score 0):

Create the timer only once:

```js
var timer;  // global timer?

function updateStats() {
     i++; // increment
     alert("Im running! increment is " + i);

     checkCondition(i);
}

function checkCondition(i) {
     if(i == 2) {
        alert("condition met, resetting timer!");
        clearInterval(timer);
     }
}

var i = 0;
timer = setInterval(updateStats, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work, and you do clear the timeout, the problem is that you're creating multiple timers each time you call updateStats, and you're overwriting timer each time, loosing the handle to the other timers. Why are you calling the function that creates new timers every time, you're adding a lot of timers ?

I'm guessing you're really trying to do this, where the interval is only created once, and not on every iteration

```
var timer;

function updateStats(i) {
    function inner() {
        i++;
        alert("Im running! increment is " + i);
        checkCondition(i);
    }

    timer = setInterval(inner, 5000);
    inner();
}

function checkCondition(i) {
     if(i == 2) {
        alert("condition met, resetting timer!");
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

var i = 0;
updateStats(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run `updateStats` you create an interval timer.

Inside that interval timer you run `updateStats`

So when the code first runs, you have 1 internal timer running.

After 5 seconds you have 2. After 10 seconds each of those intervals starts a new one so you have 4 and so on.

They are all sharing a single `timer` variable, so it's value will be whatever the last interval you set going was and that is the only one you stop. (while all the others keep running, doubling the number of interval timers you have running ever 5 seconds.

You need to seriously refactor your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing the timer, then immediately setting a brand new one straight away after it. setInterval only needs to be called once too. At the moment, each time your loop gets called, another instance of the timer is being made, and you only ever clear the last one.

Have a look at this:

```
var timer,i=0; 
 timer = setInterval(function() {
        updateStats();
 }, 5000);

function updateStats() {
    i++; // increment
    alert("Im running! increment is " + i);

    checkCondition();

}

function checkCondition() {
     if(i == 2) {
        alert("condition met, resetting timer!");
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ctaylr/bLz7k7oc/

Answer (score 0):

Let me simplify your code drastically:

```js
loop(0, 1000);

function loop(count, delay) {
    alert("I am running. The count is " + (++count) + ".");
    if (count === 2) alert("Condition met, stopping loop.");
    else setTimeout(loop, delay, count, delay);
}
```

```html
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script>
    (function (window, setTimeout, setInterval) {
        window.setTimeout  = fix(setTimeout);
        window.setInterval = fix(setInterval);

        function fix(timer) {
            return function (callback, interval) {
                var length = arguments.length;

                switch (length) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    throw new Error("expected at least two arguments");
                case 2:
                    return timer(callback, interval);
                default:
                    var i = 2;
                    var args = new Array(length - 2);
                    while (i < length) args[i - 2] = arguments[i++];
                    return timer(backcall, interval);
                }

                function backcall() {
                    return callback.call(this, args);
                }
            };
        }
    }(window, setTimeout, setInterval));
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Because of the way we are using `setTimeout` (i.e. with extra arguments), the above code wouldn't have worked in Internet Explorer versions less than 9 if it wasn't for the conditional polyfill that I included.